# how to remove touch action from label after moving it to a rectangle in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I apply touches move action on a label to drag it into a rectangle box it is moving with touch fine, now i want to remove touch action from label when it is dropped in rectangle how can i get this  any help.
here is my code after label drag end.

```
- (void)dragEnd:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
BOOL cancelPanGesture = YES;
if (cancelPanGesture) {
             gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
if(rectangle.frame.size.width ==  _lbl.frame.size.width){
    gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) {
    gestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
if(rectangle.frame.size.width ==  _lbl.frame.size.width){
    gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    _lbl.userInteractionEnabled = false;
    UILabel *tapLable = (UILabel *)[gestureRecognizer view]; 
    [tempLabel removeGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}
```

Comment: yes i want to disable touch from label after drag it

Comment: when it is dragged then touch should be disabled

Comment: i am asking you want to disable the label object name "_lbl" in the above if condition right

Comment: yes exactly _lbl should be disabled when is dragged

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142815/discussion-between-bhupat-bheda-and-moon).

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you :)

```
if(CGRectContainsRect(rectangle.frame, _lbl.frame){
    gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    _lbl.userInteractionEnabled = false;
    UILabel *tapLable = (UILabel *)[gestureRecognizer view]; 
    [tempLabel removeGestureRecognizer:removeGestureRecognizer];
}
```

Comment: how can i apply it on a loop of labels it just work for one label

Comment: This is just a condition. You can make a function which takes 2 argument: reference on rectangle view and the label. In that function you can put this condition.

Comment: i try but only _lbl.userInteractionEnabled = false; this working

Comment: - (void)endDrag:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    for(int i=0;i<_columnB.count;i++) {
        UILabel *tempLabel = (UILabel *)[_columnB objectAtIndex:i];
        

    BOOL cancelPanGesture = YES;
    
       if(rect.frame.size.width == _lbl.frame.size.width){
            gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
            tempLabel.userInteractionEnabled = false;
            
            
            [tempLabel removeGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
            NSLog (@"Draged");
        }

Comment: ColumnB holds my 4 labels in an array

Comment: Try this code
`- (void)endDrag:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    for(int i=0;i<_columnB.count;i++)
    {
        UILabel *tempLabel = (UILabel *)[_columnB objectAtIndex:i];
        BOOL cancelPanGesture = YES;
        if(CGRectContainsRect(rect.frame, tempLabel.frame))
        {
            gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
            tempLabel.userInteractionEnabled = false;
            [tempLabel removeGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
            NSLog (@"Draged");
        }
    }
}
 `

Comment: same issue only work for one label dragged not for all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142823/discussion-between-sarthak-gupta-and-moon).